# Is there a way to access attributes in the class of a property with said attribute?

Tags: c#

In this scenario:

```
class MyClass
{
  [MyAttribute("flag")]
  public OtherClass Property {get; set;)

  // etc.
}
```

Is there a way for code in `OtherClass` to access the "flag" without knowledge of `MyClass`?

Comment: I would be great to see more context, usage for example.

Comment: It's just because I'm trying to develop my understanding of the concept of Attributes, in this case on properties, because I haven't found an usefull example - the one above doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: [Here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)  is an useful example for attributes on properties.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Because OtherClass is totally independent and does not know where it is used. Well, in theory - yes. Load ALL classes, go through them, find all references, analyze for attribute via reflection. Depending on size and locality (in one assembly, in all assemblies) this may be slow or "oh damn, waht happened it is REALLLY slow", but yes, you can get access to all assemblies, all classes and use reflection on those.